# What image is used when latest tag is removed in ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using bitbucket pipelines to deploy a docker image previously uploaded to ECR using:

```
docker tag 
docker push
```

The two tags I am giving the newly uploaded image are the `${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}` and `latest`

In the final step of my pipeline that image gets redeployed using

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster clusterName --service $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG --force-new-deployment
```

The task definition for the ECS service is set to use `:latest`

What I would like to achieve is a proper handling of deployments that fail after the initial test and analysis step when the image has already been deployed to ECR. I would like to prevent that 'faulty' image from being deployed which is why I use bitbucket-pipelines `after-script` to untag and thus also delete that image, when a step fails:

```
if [ $BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE == 1 ]; then aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name repo/$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG --image-ids imageTag=latest; fi
if [ $BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE == 1 ]; then aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name repo/$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG --image-ids imageTag=${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}; fi
```

The task can still be restarted successfully and when I set `$BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE == 0` during my trial runs the pipeline is able to deploy "something". My question is: What image is used when there is no image with `latest` tag on ECR? Is there a way I can easily find out?

Comment: None. Read https://container-solutions.com/docker-latest-confusion/ for more information. I recommend changing your pipeline to use explicit build numbers, and get rid of `latest` entirely.